# Test if a file is deletable

Tags: c, windows

Is there any way to determine if a file can be deleted before trying DeleteFile on it. I just want to test if a DeleteFile will succeed without really deleting the file. What I want to do is to create a hardlink to a file if it is not in use and to copy it if it is in use without FILE_SHARE_DELETE(there is in the system a handle opened on it woithout FILE_SHARE_DELETE flag).

Thank you!

Comment: In general, on a preemptive multitasking OS the only way to be check if a file operation will succeed is to try it, since there's always a race condition - any other program may alter the state of the filesystem between your check and the actual operation.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer:* I don't really know anything about Windows programming. But I read documentation.

According to the MSDN documentation for [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can specify [`DELETE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the `dwDesiredAccess` parameter, which will cause the `CreateFile` call to fail if the access right is not available. (You can also specify `OPEN_EXISTING` for `dwCreationDisposition` if you don't actually want to create a new file.) That should cover your use case.

However, it's worth pointing out that there is an race condition; you might do this test and then just afterwards, before you have a chance to act on the result, someone else might open the file without the `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`. So for the test to be meaningful, you'd need to know more about the lifecycle of files than is mentioned in your question (which you indeed might know; it isn't really necessary to mention it, so if you do, just ignore this paragraph.)

Comment: Thank you. At the beginning I thought also DELETE flag is enough for the test, but it does not work. Anyway, starting from here I manage to find a solution in the end - making a CreateFile with FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE - if I receive a handle than the file is deletable. Before closing the handle using NtSetInformationFile with FILE_DISPOSITION_INFORMATION I remove FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE so this way I avoid deleting the file when closing the handle. And indeed I do have control over the lifecycle of that file - meaning that after I make the test no one should open it without SHARE_DELETE.

Comment: @user3555031: "After the test no-one should open the file without SHARE_DELETE" is almost certainly not good enough. It should be impossible *before* the test. If it is the existence of the hard-link which prevents the file from being opened, then there is a small window of vulnerability between the test and the creation of the hard-link, and I guarantee you that sooner or later a race condition will get in through the window, no matter how small it is. Sorry about the misinformation about `DELETE`; the documentation is definitely misleading if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your answers. In the end after 3 days of searching(after 2 days I posted my question here) I found I needed. At the beginning (3 days ago) I thought DELETE flag is enough for the test, but it does not work - I still am able to open a handle even there is another handle open in the system without FILE_SHARE_DELETE flag. Anyway, starting from here I manage to find a solution in the end - making a CreateFile with FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE - if I receive a valid handle than the file is deletable. Before closing the handle using NtSetInformationFile with FILE_DISPOSITION_INFORMATION I remove FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE so this way I avoid deleting the file when closing the handle. And indeed I do have control over the lifecycle of that file - meaning that after I make the test no one should open it without SHARE_DELETE - at least not the processes I control which should be enough for what I have to do.